# C# OxyPlot Textposition of PolygonAnnotation

Tags: c#, wpf, polygon, oxyplot

I am having two `PolygonAnnotation` shown on a `PlotModel`. I want to connect them via one `ArrowAnnotation`. As `Startpoint` and `Endpoint` of the `ArrowAnnotation` I want to have a defined point of respective `PolygonAnnotation`, not the clicked position. As the `Text` of each `PolygonAnnotation` is already printed in the center via `TextHorizontalAlignment` and `TextVerticalAlignment` I thought using `TextPosition` as the `DataPoint` for the respective `Startpoint` or `Endpoint` would be a good idea. Unfortunatly `TextPosition` always equals `{n. def. n. def.}`.

Any ideas how to get the position of the `Text` or another defined `Datapoint` within a `PolygonAnnotation`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way, but you could try working your way through the Visual Tree.

```
    public void FindPosition(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return;
        var plotView = (PlotView)obj;
        FindTextPosition<PlotView>(plotView).FindName(plotView.Name);
    }
    private IEnumerable<T> FindTextPosition<T>(DependencyObject parent)
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (child is TextBlock text)
            {
                if (text.Text == "Test") // Or any identifier you could specify
                {
                    var position = text.PointToScreen(new Point(0d, 0d));

                }

            }

            foreach (var other in FindTextPosition<T>(child)) yield return other;
        }
    }
```